# Python 3 trivial issue with boolean type

Tags: python, python-3.x, boolean, operator-precedence

I've typed some code in Python 3 idle and don't understand the output. Can someone explain, why this happens:

> 1 > 0 == True

```
False
```

> 1 > (0 == True)

```
True
```

> (1 > 0) == True

```
True
```

Also you can replace digits to bools and output will be the same.

Answer (score 1):

Because in Python, [comparisons can be chained arbitrarily](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons). So your expression is equivalent to

```
(1 > 0) and (0 == True)
```

the latter part of which obviously fails.

You would be surprised to see this is true in Python, but false in C:

```
5 > 4 > 3 > 2 > 1
```

Answer (score 0):

These operators all have the same precedence ([From Docs](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons))

> Unlike C, all comparison operations in Python have the same priority, which is lower than that of any arithmetic, shifting or bitwise operation.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the [chained comparison](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#comparisons). This explains the query, e.g. first expression -

```
1 > 0 == True
```

can be broken as (1>0) and (0==True), which is True and False and will return false.